# Azure Personalizers not updating the model

Tags: c#, .net, azure, botframework, azure-cognitive-services

I am working on a requirement where I am using Azure Personalizer service in my chatbot . I have created a test bot from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-personalizer-samples.
I have created personalizer and luis service in Azure and added the endpoints in appsettings.json.
Also in Azure i have added the configuration settings Reward wait time and Model update frequency as 1 min. After running the solution and giving the personalizer responses for reward Api, I donot see model getting updated and also the choices are not updating as per suggestions.
Can anyone help me with the above issue?

Comment: Can you please share the error details and Reward wait time that has been set.

Answer (score 1):

If your model is not updated. You need to download the JSON file here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-personalizer-samples/blob/master/samples/ChatbotExample/CognitiveModels/coffeebot.json

Go to your LUIS portal, Click "MANAGE" button, click "VERSION" on left and import it.

After that, you can see all versions in your LUIS. You can delete all not related version to make things clear.

Click on the Train button on the top right of the page; this will train your app on the model

Once this is done, press the Publish button and select "Production" (You can leave the Sentiment Analysis, Spell Check, and Speech Priming fields set to Off). NOTE: Once you publish your app on LUIS portal for the first time, it takes some time for the endpoint to become available, about 5 minutes of wait should be sufficient.

Please always make sure you are using the version you want to use.

[image]